# Network Profile: Top Questions are scored by upvotes only, but Top Answers by total + -?

Tags: bug, sorting, network-profile, top-questions, top-answers

Is this intentional?

Both the question and the answer received (n + 1) upvotes and 1 downvote.  On the Network Profile page, the **net** score is reflected on the **answer**, but not the question.  The **question** still shows *either the max score it ever had* (maybe from caching, but it's over a year old) or else *a measure of only positive feedback*.

Visiting the actual question post shows the correct current net score, which is different from the one on the network profile (again, only for the Q, not the A).

Screenshots of discrepancy in question score, but agreement in answer score:
[image]

Comment: Bug, not cache, lack of proper synchronization of the network profile. There's dupe, I'll look for it later. (However, it's pretty rare, most scores are fine)

Comment: That's odd, the related question from 4 years ago didn't show up in the similar questions preview before I posted this.  If that was the same issue, it looks like it's just a coincidence that it has happened to a question and not to any of the answers

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Whoa, simultaneous commenting! Thanks, but I think the dupe might have just suggested itself?

Comment: Yeah that's the one. Looks like that when a user is removed, the updated scores are not reflected in the network profile, and maybe more events are not reflecting there as well. :(